# Stuck Setting Up NPGSQL for Excel

Tags: postgresql, npgsql

For the last couple of days I have been trying to figure out how to configure the NPGSQL (.net 7.0) connector for use with Excel/Power Query and whilst I can get it install in the GAC I can't seem to get Excel to recognise it.

I've downloaded 7.0.2 from GitHub and compiled the code, I've also downloaded the NuGet package and extracted the DLL and in both cases I can register it in the GAC (and verified it's installed), I've amended the machine.config file and added the DbProviderFactory string, I've tried creating a App.Config file and placing it in "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config".

I've also tried adding some additional dependencies, mono.security and Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions but I still can't get it to work with Excel.

Any help on where I'm going wrong or what I actually need to do to install the connector would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm struggling with this as well though I think I'm still a few steps behind you.
I need to connect Power Query in Excel to my PostgreSQL server in the cloud.  I need to be able to excecute custom queries from the connection in excel.


I tried geting the MSI installer but I was not able to find it un Github.

Comment: This I can at least help you with, https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/releases?page=2 if you look at asset's for v4.0.13 you will see the MSI file, this will install and enable NPGSQL in Excel for you.